# How to script a button click in a separate JS file rather than HTML Script Header tag

Tags: javascript, html

So I need some help, I am new to JS and I need to to find a solution to the problem I am having. I am trying to create a button when it clicks changes a piece of text. When I create a JS function in the script tag header and reference the function in the button onclick it works, but it doesn't work in a separate JS file. The HTML code is below. Hopefully, someone can help me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="changetext.js"></script>
  <script>
    function Button() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hello";
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    function Button2() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hi";
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <p id="demo"> hi</p>

  <button id="ButtonText" onclick="Button()"> Click Here To Change The Text</button>
  <button id="ButtonText2" onclick="Button2()"> Click Here To Change The Text Back</button>




  <script type="text/javascript" src="changetext.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add your function inside changetext.js without script tag

Comment: Learn about [event attachment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Using inline `onclick` statements is not ideal for various reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an example...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>example</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p id="demo"> hi</p>

    <button id="ButtonText" onclick="Button()"> Click Here To Change The Text</button>
    <button id="ButtonText2" onclick="Button2()"> Click Here To Change The Text Back</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="changetext.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

first you need remove your script.. we include script only if you dont use a external js.

**on your external js(changetext.js)**

```
  function Button(){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hello from button 1";
    }
    function Button2(){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hellow from button2";
    }
```

**result:**

[image: result]

if you dont use a external js the code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>example</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"> hi</p>

<button id="ButtonText" onclick="Button();"> Click Here To Change The Text</button>
<button id="ButtonText2" onclick="Button2();"> Click Here To Change The Text Back</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="changetext.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function Button(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hello from button 1";
}
function Button2(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hellow from button2";
}
</script>
```

we write the code js in the tag **script** good luck !!

Comment: ah I noticed my script tag was in the header, instead of the footer, im going through JS at the moment, why does this specific line of code not work with the script tag in the head?

Answer (score 0):

Write your function in `changetext.js` and make sure that is in same place as your HTML file.

change   `onclick` to `onClick`

and remove your `script` tags in the `head`